# Filtering Data in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to ask a simple and like a trash question because(I am noob).
I want to filter DataGridView to show only those entries who have a value greater than 0(zero) in an specific column.
I am finding and filtering data with Name like

```
If searchTxt.Text = "" Then
            Call notFound()
            Exit Sub
        Else
            StudentsBindingSource.Filter = "(Convert(ID, 'System.String') LIKE '" & searchTxt.Text & "')" & _
                "OR (Name LIKE '" & searchTxt.Text & "')"
            If StudentsBindingSource.Count <> 0 Then
                With StudentsDataGridView1
                    .DataSource = StudentsBindingSource
                End With
            Else
                MsgBox("The search item was not found.", _
                       MsgBoxStyle.Information, "No Data Found!")
                StudentsBindingSource.Filter = Nothing

            End If

        End If
```

now i just want to find those entries who have >0 amount in balance column.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you need an "AND" in your filter.  Make sure to separate your filter parts correctly with parenthesis.

Comment: `.Filter = $"ID > 0 AND Name LIKE '%{searchTxt.Text}%'"`. I assume the `StudentsBindingSource` is already the DataSource of your DGV, so remove the assignment (`StudentsDataGridView1.DataSource = StudentsBindingSource`). You don't need to reset the datasource when you apply a filter.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Bro this code was my example. I have tab control in one tab i have only placed a DataGridView and nothing else like any textbox. so i want a simple code to filter data in balance colum, it means i want to see all the students who have not paid their fees, thats why balance column has >0 value like 500 or 1000